# Grub rescue problems

Tags: boot, grubrescue

So I installed unbutu recently I went to my first boot and it told me
Error no such device then error unknown file system it enters rescue mode. I tried listing the file types but all the drives but they all say filesystem unknown

Comment: What brand/model system? Dual boot or just Ubuntu? UEFI or BIOS install, most systems are UEFI. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 I did it alongside my other files and I don't know about the bios or uefi

Comment: Run Boot-Repair from live installer & post link to report it can run.

Comment: Doing it on a hp pavilion series and I did it becomes windows. I tried boot repair but now it comes with saying windows is damaged and I need to repair but when I choose options it goes back to the same screen

Comment: Boot-Repair cannot fix Windows. If you have Windows issues you have to fix those with Windows tools.If UEFI, you should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. Grub only boots working Windows and if Windows is hibernated/fast start up on, then grub will not boot it.

Comment: I'm not trying to boot into Windows I already installed Ubuntu and it's not booting into it. I want he'll going into unbuntu .

Comment: Post link to Summary Report. But if HP, it may only want to boot in UEFI mode from an entry that says "Windows Boot Manager". Sometimes creating an UEFI entry that is really grub or shim but says it is Windows works. Others use rEFInd. And many can just boot the "hard drive" entry. See IV for efibootmgr entry to create a Windows description that boots Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win